# Looking for Riley again?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> My Prefix is a body of water,
>
> My infix body part;
>
> My suffix looks like a letter,
>
> If you just invert.

**Tell me what am I?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Search

My Prefix is a body of water,

> Sea

My infix body part;

> Ear

My suffix looks like a letter,

If you just invert.

> Arch - which, if you invert, looks like a 'U'.

Title

> To search means to look for.

Comment: ha ha, guess the title was a dead giveaway